# PHP Contact Form sending blank emails, text input not showing up in email

Tags: php, forms, email

I am having some trouble with my php email form. I asked this question earlier but, but realized it was poorly worded so I deleted that and tried again. I am new to this forum, I'm still getting used to how to post.

My html contact form is going through but sending blank emails.

Here us my HTML form:

```
<form id="contact_form" class="cf" name="contact_form" action="mailscript.php" method="POST">

    <div id="left_form_container"> 
      <div class="half_left_cf">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="input_name" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="input_email" placeholder="Email address">
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="input_subject" placeholder="Subject">
      </div>   
    </div>

    <div id="right_form_container">
        <div class="half_right_cf">
            <textarea name="message" id="input_message" type="text" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            <div id="submit_container">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="input_submit">
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>

</form>
```

And here is my php code:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$to = "mail@thomasjeffery.design";
$body = "From: ".$name."\n E-Mail: ".$email."\n Message:\n" .$message;



if(mail ($to, $subject, $body)){


echo "<script>
alert('Thank you for sending your message!');
window.location.href='index.php';
</script>";}
    else {echo "Mail was not sent!";}


?>
```

The email works (it sends an email), and the echo displays a "thank you" and returns the user to the main page, but the form information from the contact form is not being sent through..

Instead, the email just reads: 
"From: 
E-mail:
Message:".

Can anyone tell me why it is not including the input fields from my html form? It seems very simple but I cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: What is the output when you echo $_POST['name'] ?

Comment: Also what are you sending through the form, are there special characters?

Answer (score 0):

You may try do some debugging with your request like:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_REQUEST);
print_r($_GET);
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
```

Also, you gotta make sure that your form method attribute either POST or GET method.

Comment: it just comes out as "array ()" :/ So I don't think the input is actually coming through at all.

Comment: Yeah, if it's empty arrays then it's definitely something wrong with your data submission. My suggestion, double check your <form>, add those debug codes I mentioned earlier in action page, then add exit() function. Make sure you get the data from your form.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of your code it seems you forgot to add a form opening tag. "`<form>`"

eg.

```
<form method="post" action="thepagetosubmit.php">
```

possible fullcode.

```
 <form method="post" action="thepagetosubmit.php">
    <div id="left_form_container"> 
      <div class="half_left_cf">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="input_name" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="input_email" placeholder="Email address">
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="input_subject" placeholder="Subject">
      </div>   
    </div>

    <div id="right_form_container">
        <div class="half_right_cf">
            <textarea name="message" id="input_message" type="text" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            <div id="submit_container">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="input_submit">
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Sorry, it looks like my opening form tag didn't paste over when i added it. But I do have that.